# Trying to display a chart using vegaEmbed and a JSON object generated with altair. vegaEmbed is interpreting JSON object as URL. Any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, altair, vega

so sort of a niche question, but I was hoping someone else knew the answer to this, I haven't found anything useful in the vega or altair documentation.

So to start off, this is the situation:

I am running a Flask webserver, where the user will define a few parameters, and a query is sent to the python backend. Once there, the python will use the altair library to create a chart, which is converted to a JSON variable, like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.17.0.json",
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "continuousHeight": 300,
      "continuousWidth": 400
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "data-1b5b13f7e805a5d4e2f2e2e30ef5c4ac"
  },
  "datasets": {
    "data-1b5b13f7e805a5d4e2f2e2e30ef5c4ac": [
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-09T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.7937062937062938,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 170.0,
        "volume": 229.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-10T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.80239898989899,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 433.0,
        "volume": 510.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-11T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8085291557876414,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-12T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8209389281262983,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 312.0,
        "volume": 359.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-13T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8240426563257393,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 148.0,
        "volume": 180.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-14T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8230588235294117,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 49.0,
        "volume": 62.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-15T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8241419205553413,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 388.0,
        "volume": 468.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-16T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8161218424962853,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 140.0,
        "volume": 203.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-17T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8069936421435059,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 15.0,
        "volume": 31.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-18T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8104799216454457,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-19T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8301119023397762,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 147.0,
        "volume": 153.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-20T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8388858547241944,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 337.0,
        "volume": 375.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-21T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8388858547241944,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-22T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.836453744493392,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 295.0,
        "volume": 344.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-23T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8527483610690872,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 320.0,
        "volume": 347.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-24T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8547631441957314,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-25T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8630419821059876,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-26T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8437067773167358,
        "averages": "10d MA",
        "passing": 106.0,
        "volume": 196.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-09T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8068622025456558,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 170.0,
        "volume": 229.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-10T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8104872702748271,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 433.0,
        "volume": 510.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-11T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8104872702748271,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-12T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8102062216008389,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 312.0,
        "volume": 359.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-13T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8050169009073118,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 148.0,
        "volume": 180.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-14T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8078844095611845,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 49.0,
        "volume": 62.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-15T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8088911599386817,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 388.0,
        "volume": 468.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-16T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.7940911547468924,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 140.0,
        "volume": 203.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-17T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.7889539136795903,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 15.0,
        "volume": 31.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-18T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.7971150243536905,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-19T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8069655427936273,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 147.0,
        "volume": 153.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-20T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8157631526305261,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 337.0,
        "volume": 375.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-21T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8219907968031,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-22T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8276107032914989,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 295.0,
        "volume": 344.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-23T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.838111715274345,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 320.0,
        "volume": 347.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-24T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.838111715274345,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-25T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.838111715274345,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 0.0,
        "volume": 0.0
      },
      {
        "Dates": "2022-07-26T00:00:00",
        "Yields": 0.8257612373127114,
        "averages": "20d MA",
        "passing": 106.0,
        "volume": 196.0
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "averages",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Dates",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "format": "%"
      },
      "field": "Yields",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  },
  "mark": "line"
}
```

This JSON object is sent back to the frontend, and I attempt to use vegaEmbed to insert it into my HTML, which looks a bit like this, where responseData is that JSON I included above, and chartBody is the id of the div I want my chart embedded within:

```
populateGraph(responseData, "chartBody");

const populateGraph = (url, div) => {
    var opt = {
        mode: "vega-lite",
        renderer: "svg",
        actions: { export: true, source: false, editor: false }
    };

    vegaEmbed("#" + div, url, opt, function (error, result) {
            vegaTooltip.vegaLite(result.view, url);
        }
    );
}
```

So, I know that my structure works with this as the URL, as a graph is displayed in my frontend: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/examples/bar-chart.vg.json"

That leaves me with the question, which is, why, when I use the JSON included at the top of this question, do I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://localhost:51962/%7B%20%20%22$schema%22:%20%22https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.17.0.json%22,%20%20%22config%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%22view%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%22continuousHeight%22:%20300,%20%20%20%20%20%20%22continuousWidth%22:%20400%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7D,%20%20%22data%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%22name%22:%20%22data-1b5b13f7e805a5d4e2f2e2e30ef5c4ac%22%20%20%7D,%20%20%22datasets%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%22data-1b5b13f7e805a5d4e2f2e2e30ef5c4ac%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-09T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.7937062937062938,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20170.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20229.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-10T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.80239898989899,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20433.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20510.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-11T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8085291557876414,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-12T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8209389281262983,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20312.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20359.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-13T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8240426563257393,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20148.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20180.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-14T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8230588235294117,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%2049.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%2062.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-15T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8241419205553413,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20388.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20468.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-16T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8161218424962853,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20140.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20203.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-17T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8069936421435059,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%2015.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%2031.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-18T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8104799216454457,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-19T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8301119023397762,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20147.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20153.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-20T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8388858547241944,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20337.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20375.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-21T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8388858547241944,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-22T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.836453744493392,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20295.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20344.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-23T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8527483610690872,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20320.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20347.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-24T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8547631441957314,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-25T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8630419821059876,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-26T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8437067773167358,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2210d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20106.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20196.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-09T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8068622025456558,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20170.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20229.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-10T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8104872702748271,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20433.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20510.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-11T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8104872702748271,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-12T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8102062216008389,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20312.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20359.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-13T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8050169009073118,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20148.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20180.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-14T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8078844095611845,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%2049.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%2062.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-15T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8088911599386817,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20388.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20468.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-16T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.7940911547468924,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20140.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20203.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-17T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.7889539136795903,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%2015.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%2031.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-18T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.7971150243536905,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-19T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8069655427936273,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20147.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20153.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-20T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8157631526305261,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20337.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20375.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-21T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8219907968031,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-22T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8276107032914989,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20295.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20344.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-23T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.838111715274345,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20320.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20347.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-24T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.838111715274345,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-25T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.838111715274345,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%200.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%200.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dates%22:%20%222022-07-26T00:00:00%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Yields%22:%200.8257612373127114,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22averages%22:%20%2220d%20MA%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22passing%22:%20106.0,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22volume%22:%20196.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20]%20%20%7D,%20%20%22encoding%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%22color%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22:%20%22averages%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22nominal%22%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%22x%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22:%20%22Dates%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22temporal%22%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%22y%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%22axis%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22format%22:%20%22%%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22:%20%22Yields%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22quantitative%22%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7D,%20%20%22mark%22:%20%22line%22%7D
```

I mean, the obvious answer is that the vegaEmbed is parsing my JSON variable as a URL, which it is not, and so it throws this error. That being said, I was hoping that there was a way to make this work, as I want this whole process to be achieved without saving my JSON variables locally, as there might be an indeterminate number of graphs being hosted at any one time. Is there a way around this? I assume I am missing something simple, but I can't find it. If anyone would like to help me, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!